# Django - Get related objects

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-related-manager

I have 3 Models (lets say A, B, C). Model **C** has both **A** and **B** as Foreign keys. Now I have primary_key of **A** and I want to retrieve the list of related **B** objects.

I want entire object of **B** not just fields which I can get using values() or values_list(). My Models are as below:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    roll_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name='c_a')
    b = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name='c_b')
```

Comment: Try this `c.objects.filter(a=primary_key_a).values('name','roll_number','b__name','b__description')`

Comment: I wanted list of B objects, not just fields

Comment: This will provide you all the rows in b with matched primary_key_a and also data of matched entry in b table also

Comment: I need B objects because I want to use Serializer on those objects and return data. Just getting the values will not suffice in my condition.

Comment: Then instead of 'b__name'  just use 'b' and then pass it to serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly modify the answer from @Piyush S. Wanare like that:

```
c.objects.filter(a=primary_key_a).values('b')
```

Or if you only want a list with only b objects you can use `values_list()`:

```
c.objects.filter(a=primary_key_a).values_list('b', flat=True)
```

This gives you a flat list of b (in this case). `values` returns a dictionary, `values_list` is similar but the output is a list of tuples instead of a dict. The additional option `flat=True` (works if only one one field is retrieved) returns a flat list of objects instead of a list of tuples of objects.

The docs for reference:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list